# Simple example of hyperparameter search with distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Can anyone offer an example of hyperparameter search using distributed tensorflow?

All the distributed tensorflow examples I've seen use the same computation graph; what if I want to try varying the number of hidden units and number of hidden layers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just run completely separate processes on each machine with different hyperparameter settings?

Comment: That's what we've wound up doing.  Of course we can't use the distributed Tensorflow environment to coordinate this (we use a conventional batch job scheduler).  It would be nice to do this all within Tensorflow, of course.